# LINQ returning variable number of outputs for each input (point list to line list)

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list like (1,5,8,9) and I want to return a list like (10,50,50,80,80,90).

Is LINQ suitable for such a transformation?

The actual application is given a list of objects with calculable (x,y) coordinate and returning list of line segments between the objects.

Comment: is there any pattern  or relationship between input and output? Can you provide some code?

Comment: What's the logic of converting 1, 5, 8, 9 to 10,50,80,80,90? Can you share the details of actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: So, you want to multiple every item with 10 and duplicate them except first and last?

Comment: By which condition do you determine whether a value is duplicated (50, 80) or not (10, 90)? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: You can use Select() and SelectMany() to generate arbitrary extra elements. Whether it's appropriate or not entirely depends on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: I thnk you want to multiply each item by 10. So here is the logic  `List<int> ls = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            ls = ls.Select(x => x * 10).ToList();`

Comment: Sorry my description wasn't clearer. The output sequence is a flattened list of pairs (10,50),(50,80),(80,90) representing the (scaled) spans between the input values.
i.e. transforming list-of-posts to list-of-rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With given input you can get the expected result using the following code, by multiplying every item by `10`, duplicating them using `SelectMany` and `Enumerable.Repeat` and skipping first and last item

```cs
 var list = new List<int> { 1, 5, 8, 9 };
 var result = list
     .Select(x => x * 10).SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x, 2))
     .Skip(1).SkipLast(1)
     .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', result)); //returns 10,50,50,80,80,90
```

Comment: @WarwickAllison Does it answer your question, do you more details or information?

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! Obviously my actual transformation isn't just multiplying by 10, but this was the clearest way I could think the express my problem. Actual code is taking an index into a list of objects, retrieving their 2D position, and outputing a sequence of points representing a sequence of lines between the objects indexed in the original list.